# eager load with dynamic condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to execute an eager load using a dynamic condition? More specifically:

```
u_id = params[:user_id]
Container.includes(:items).where("items.user_id =?", u_id)
```

This obviously doesn't give me all the containers but with only items of a certain `user_id` as it applies the `where` condition to the entire query rather than just `:items`, but is there a way to accomplish this using ARel, or does it require a custom SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `scoped` on your query:

```
Container.where("items.user_id =?", u_id).includes(:items).scoped
```

This will return an Arel object rather than a database query.

Try it out in `Rails Console` and you can see the Arel object that is created compared to when you run it without `scoped`.

Comment: This gives me a better understanding of scoped. Right now the query only returns containers that contain an item. Is it possible to eager load items for a given user and get all the containers, even if they don't contain any items?

Comment: If you had user_id on the Container then it would be relatively easy. `Container.where("user_id = ?", params[:user.id]).include(:items).scoped` this would select all containers for a given user and then include the items which related to selected containers. If you didn't have `user_id` on the container then I don't have the answer right on top of my head. If I find anything further I will post it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try modifying the design, perhaps that's what's causing my difficulty. Currently all `Users` can get all `Containers` but only their `Items` within those containers. I've got it working with a little logic in the view, but it's causing the delightful N+1 query problem.